# Failing Jenkins build after checkstyle reports

Tags: jenkins

I want to reduce the load on our Jenkins slaves and give developers a quicker feedback when there are checkstyle/findbugs issues. Currently the build runs through, but is still marked as failed if there are checkstyle issues.

```
stage ('Reports') {
    step([$class: 'FindBugsPublisher', canComputeNew: false, canRunOnFailed: true, defaultEncoding: '', excludePattern: '', failedTotalHigh: '0', failedTotalNormal: '200', failedTotalLow: '350', healthy: '', includePattern: '', pattern: '**/spotbugsXml.xml', unHealthy: ''])
    step([$class: 'CheckStylePublisher', canComputeNew: false, canRunOnFailed: true, defaultEncoding: '', healthy: '', pattern: '**/maven_checks.xml ',failedTotalHigh: '0', failedTotalNormal: '0',failedTotalLow: '0', unHealthy: ''])
    step([$class: 'WarningsPublisher', canComputeNew: false, canResolveRelativePaths: false, consoleParsers: [[parserName: 'Maven'], [parserName: 'userdef-protobuf'], [parserName: 'userdef-xtend']], defaultEncoding: '', excludePattern: '', healthy: '', includePattern: '', messagesPattern: '', unHealthy: ''])
}
```

I want this stage to fail the build immediately if there were problems, and not wait until the end of the tests etc. Currently subsequent stages are still executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same issue and as lame as it seems, I currently do a simple `grep` on my `checkstyle.xml` to see if there are errors, and fail te build if so:

```
def foundErrors = sh(
    script: "cat test-reports/checkstyle.xml | grep 'severity=\"error\"' | wc -l",
    returnStdout: true
)
if (foundErrors.toInteger() > 0) {
    error("Build failed because of errors in static code analysis.")
}
```

I know, it's very lame, but in my case it does the job. Not sure if this is helpful for you since I have only 1 XML file to worry about and that does not seem te be the case for you, but hey, at least it's something ;-)